# Duplicate rows and change category value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have Table 1 with many columns. I want to duplicate all rows with category=16 but I want the copied rows to have category=17. What is the correct query to do this? Thanks.

Comment: It would be best if you provide a sample of the data you have along with your desired output.

Comment: You necessary INSERT or simple SELECT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into Table1(category, Column1, Column2)
select 17, Column1, Column2
from Table1
where category = 16
```

Comment: If I have 30 columns, is there a way to make the query short instead of putting Category, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7, Column8...Column30?

Comment: @damdeok Nope but you can drag and drop the column list from the object explorer to save you from actually typing all the column names. Grab a hold of the `columns` node under a table and drop it in the query editor.